# How can a span id that div classes are applied to be looped?

Tags: javascript, html, css, loops

I'm new to coding, and I'm trying to learn the basics. I wanted to practice what I learned by making flashcards (nothing complicated like saving it, importing it, or exporting it). So far, I made a table that the user can edit. I know how to gather data from the table, but I don't know how to make a CSS flashcard appear every time the user adds a card to the table. I am aware that the code will not work since I put the CSS in JavaScript since this code is just meant to show what I am *trying* to do. Also, if I am taking a completely wrong approach, please let me know. Thank you! Please excuse the poor variable naming, I was just testing some things.

```
<script>

 function getFlashcardValue() {
 
 for (var repeat = 0; repeat < 200; repeat++) {
 var Table = document.getElementById('flashcardsTable');
 
 var column1 = 0;
 var column2 = 1;
 
 var numberOfFlashcards = 2;
 
 for (var row = 0; row < numberOfFlashcards; row++) {
 
 var Cells = Table.rows.item(1).cells;
 
 var Question1 = Cells.item(column1).innerHTML;
 
 
 var Cells1 = Table.rows.item(1).cells;
 
 var Answer1 = Cells.item(column2).innerHTML;
 
 
 document.getElementById("myFlashcardQuestion" + row).innerHTML =  Question1;
 
 document.getElementById("myFlashcardAnswer" + row).innerHTML =  Answer1;
 
 <div class="flip-card">
  <div class="flip-card-inner">
    <div class="flip-card-front">
    <span id="myFlashcardQuestion1"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="flip-card-back">
    <span id="myFlashcardAnswer1"></span>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
}
 
 }
 
}
</script>

<p style = "font-size: 25px">Hover over the flashcard to flip it!</p>


<style>
.flip-card {
  background-color: transparent;
  width: 350px;
  height: 175px;
  margin: auto;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  perspective: 1000px;
}

.flip-card-inner {
  position: relative;
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  transition: transform 0.6s;
  transform-style: preserve-3d;
  box-shadow: 0 4px 8px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
}

.flip-card:hover .flip-card-inner {
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}

.flip-card-front, .flip-card-back {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  -webkit-backface-visibility: hidden;
  backface-visibility: hidden;
}

.flip-card-front {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 350px;
  height: 175px;
  color: black;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-alignment: center;
}

.flip-card-back {
  background-color: red;
  color: white;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-alignment: center;
  transform: rotateY(180deg);
}
</style>
```

Comment: Can i see an image/draw of what you aspect as result form your code?

Comment: One of the approach that I can suggest is to have a section which has all the information that you want to edit. Add one save button on click of save use your logic to create the div and append it to a container div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So first of all you can create a code snippet in stackoverflows editor (see below), or use jsfiddle and post a shared-link.
It depends on which action the user has to do after he enters the data.
If it is, for example, a button click, then it is possible to call a function that shows the user's input in the flashcard. Now if you want that for every single Q&A you have to create Elements in the for loop and edit them there. Here a little example.

```js
var allCards = document.getElementById("allCards");
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++) { //i used 5, you should use length of data
  var question = document.createElement("div");
  question.textContent = "Question " + i;
  question.classList.add("flip-card");
  allCards.appendChild(question);
}
```

```css
.flip-card {
  background-color: lightblue;
  width: 350px;
  height: 175px;
  margin: 10px auto;
  padding: 5px 5px;
  font-size: 35px;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="allCards"></div>
```

**Edit:**
As promised, here is an example of how you can set up the flip cards.

https://jsfiddle.net/ybu59hfp/1/

Your concern should now be resolved. If you have any further questions, feel free to write to me in the chat or read a little about JavaScript on the Internet.

Comment: Thank you WhiteEagle, this was very helpful. However, I can't figure out how to make the answer and question back to back on the card, as well as how to have the flipping motion. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Also, please excuse the poor variable names, I've just been testing some things out.

Comment: The motion of the card worked, you don´t have to change the id´s and classes. Just create the answers same as the question in the for loop.

Comment: But how would I make them back to back? When I didn't change the IDs, it just alternated cards (one was Hello, the next was Hola, and so on). What I want is the question on one side, and when I hover and it flips, it should show the answer on the back. When I stop hovering, it should turn back to the question. The reason I had made a second class is that I want the answer side to be red. Thanks!

Comment: Yes you changed your code after i answered first time, idk why. It was working well with css, if you provide me the code again (jsfiddle) i could show you how but like i said it is exactly how i explained for the answers side too.

Comment: Okay, I have the original code again, should I change the code in my original question? Or should I do it in a different way? I'm sorry, I'm new to stack overflow.